# How to start a workflow and pass in it values from associations

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a ready-made requester that contains the data of an already running workflow. I need to implement the copying of this workflow. That is, a new workflow must be created that will contain data from the requester, including properties and associations. Accordingly, I have 2 questions:

1. How can I transfer data from associations to a new workflow?
2. Will all the data be available in the execution of workflow at the startup? If not, then how can they be made available, for example, at the start of the workflow itself.

I already found several examples of how to run a workflow in Java, but there only properties were passed in the property collection, without associations.